# Issue with size f array with paginator paginate Class in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP, I stuck at a point. 
I have two tables , user and payment and I have put hasMany relation for those and applied condition on paginator paginate to search for specific payment type. While searching for some fields, it returns empty array of payment, but paginator paginate class shows total count '1' because it returns user array. Below is the array, I am getting:-

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 80
                [username] => a
                [email] => a@a.com
            )

        [PaymentInfo] => Array
            (

            )

    )
```

)

I want to know how I can use paginator paginate class so, it can show total records '0' if payment method array is empty.
Please help me to get out from this.

Comment: Can you show your model's hasMany relation code? and your query

Comment: Thanks @SamHecquet for your reponse, I have solved it out by using join alias and then, added condition with paginate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your association is properly set both side.

In your situation model 'User' will have 'hasMany' relation with 'Payment' as well you have to set 'belongsto' relation with 'User' model in 'Payment' Model.

If you don't have any payment records added for specific user in database then Payment array will be blank.

So first of all check your association first and check if payment record are exist or not.